# How to apply a function before comparison in an esqueleto query

Tags: database, haskell, esqueleto

For a query simple as that

```
runDb . select . from $ \cell -> do
  where_ $ cell ^. CellCode ==. val "x"
  return cell
```

I want to apply a function before the comparison of the field value with "x". The reason is that the cell code has trailing spaces in the database and nothing easier than trimming them away, e.g. with [strip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text.html#v:strip) from `Data.Text`. However, my initial approach of using `fmap` (twice) resulted in

```
No Instance for (Functor SqlExpr)
```

I know that there are functions provides by Esqueleto, like `just`, that accomplish similar things specifically (I couldn't find the implementation of `just`, though).

Is there a way to apply any function on the packed value?

While writing: in my specific case, I just might want to use `like`.

EDIT: Added the specific function  I want to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://blog.jenkster.com/2015/07/extending-esqueleto-for-type-safe-postgresql-queries.html) for a post that adds the postgresql function [`trim`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```hs
import Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql

trim :: (IsString s) => SqlExpr (Value s) -> SqlExpr (Value s) -> SqlExpr (Value s)
trim pattern target =
    unsafeSqlFunction "trim" (unsafeSqlBinOp "FROM" pattern target)
```

(If you're not using postgres, you may need to consult the documentation from your database to find if it supports something similar.)

`unsafeSqlFunction` can be used to import any function your database supports, but it is unsafe because you have the responsibility to make sure the type signature is actually what your database expects. The name will be copied literally to your SQL.

`unsafeSqlBinOp` is similar, but it defines a binary operation: `unsafeSqlBinOp "FROM" "a" "b"` is translated into the SQL `"a" FROM "b"`.

With this, you should be able to do:

```
runDb . select . from $ \cell -> do
    where_ $ trim " " (cell ^. CellCode) ==. val "x"
    return cell
```

Answer (score 2):

What kind of function to you want to apply?

Here is how someone added the ability to call the `chr()` function in a query:

https://github.com/krisajenkins/esqueleto/commit/fa1d1c888770e297fef52d76b6cb68342a6c0376

If it is a built-in function (or a user-definable function), perhaps you can do something similar.

Comment: Interesting, based on the example in your link, I understand that the reason why SqlExpr has no Functor instance is that it does indeed live in SQL land ... I guess there is no real solution to the problem how I posed it unless SQL implements something like strip.